# Managing python modules 101

Tags: python, debian, pip, conda

I am very confused, how to handle python's modules. There are multiple ways of installing packages. I am currently using three ways.

1) Packages of the linux distribution

Currently, many of the most popular modules/packets, like ipython, it is possible to install them via the distribution package manager. This leaves me with a system wide access of the package. I don't have to do anything about my PATHs, user access rights. It just work and until now, it was my most favorite method.

2) Pip or conda

As started to use packages, which are not that famous, they don't have a distribution package. So i have to obtain them elsewhere. Until now, if i couldn't find it in my distribution, i could just use pip to install any other necessary package. Conda is another option though.

My Question:

What is the "best" approach. I mean all possibilities do exactly the same, in the view of the user. I would like to use one, so i don't get confused, however as i stated, not everything is available everywhere. I am forced to use all of them right now. This is very annoying, especially in terms of update, conflicts, user rights and access, path variables, not even mentioning python 2.7 and 3.x "war".

So how do you do it? How do you maintain a system (i.e. a desktop) with so many different package managers. Do you stick do pip/conda only, installing everything for yourself(i.e. your home directory)?

Comment: This is a good question and one problem that has been plaguing Python (and not only) since a long time. However the question is not well suited to Stack Overflow, since it is mostly opinion based. For what is worth, I think you are already doing the best you can.

Comment: Yes, it is a opinioun based, but i wanted to hear opinions, and choose from them myself :)

Comment: Not questioning what you want or your right to ask: it simply does not conform well to the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of this site.

Comment: Yes, i know that. However i don't have a better place to ask this question

Answer (score 2):

The Python documentation recommends pip for installing python models:

> pip is the preferred installer program. Starting with Python 3.4, it is included by default with the Python binary installers.

For a more complete overview, you can check out the [documentation on installing modules](https://docs.python.org/3.6/installing/index.html).

In terms of dealing with the conflicts you've mentioned, you should be using virtual environments, either with [pyenv](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/scripts.html#scripts-pyvenv) or [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html). Virtual environments allow you to use different modules or versions of modules for different projects. Using virtual environments also allows you to replicate that environment elsewhere, for instance, on a server.